# How can I require a method argument in Java to implement multiple interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, multiple-inheritance

It's legal to do this in Java:

```
 void spew(Appendable x)
 {
     x.append("Bleah!\n");
 }
```

How can I do this (syntax not legal):

```
 void spew(Appendable & Closeable x)
 {
     x.append("Bleah!\n");
     if (timeToClose())
         x.close();
 }
```

**I would like if possible to force callers to use objects that are both Appendable and Closeable, without requiring a specific type.** There are multiple standard classes that do this, e.g. BufferedWriter, PrintStream, etc.

If I define my own interface

```
 interface AppendableAndCloseable extends Appendable, Closeable {}
```

that won't work since the standard classes that implement Appendable and Closeable do not implement my interface AppendableAndCloseable (unless I don't understand Java as well as I think I do... empty interfaces still add uniqueness above and beyond their superinterfaces).

The closest I can think of is to do one of the following:

1. pick one interface (e.g. Appendable), and use runtime tests to ensure the argument is an `instanceof` the others. Downside: problem not caught at compile time.
2. require multiple arguments (catches compile-time correctness but looks dorky):

   ```
   void spew(Appendable xAppend, Closeable xClose)
   {
       xAppend.append("Bleah!\n");
       if (timeToClose())
           xClose.close();
   }
   ```

Comment: That is sure lacking. But what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could do it with generics:

```
public <T extends Appendable & Closeable> void spew(T t){
    t.append("Bleah!\n");
    if (timeToClose())
        t.close();
}
```

Your syntax was *almost* right, actually.

Comment: Does this work for implements as well? I am trying to make a parameter object have to be serialzable?

Comment: @Zapnologica: For implementing an interface? No, you can't put additional type restrictions on a generic parameter that was declared in the interface.